# Process .csv files successively and extract rows whenever a specific column has non-empty cells

Tags: python, csv

I am developing a code to process multiple .csv files in a for loop and then extract (into new .csv files) only the rows that match non-empty string cells across a specific column named "20210-2.0". The non-empty string cells are named the same (i.e. 20210-2.0). Here is a screenshot showing part of the csv file:

https://uoe-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/gpapanas_ed_ac_uk/EayBblFTHmVJvRfsB6h8Vr4B09IfjQ2L1I5OQKUN2p5wzw?e=2gXW61

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

path = './'

all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

li = []

for filename in all_files:

    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None)
    li.append(df)
    df = li[li['20201-2.0'].notnull()]

    print('extracting info from cvs...')
    print(df)

    # You can now export all outcomes in new csv files
    file_name = filename + 'new' + '.csv'
    save_path = os.path.abspath(
        os.path.join(
            path, file_name
        )
    )
    print('saving ...')
    export_csv = df.to_csv(save_path, index=None)
```

I get the following error:

```
df = li[li['20201-2.0'].notnull()]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: You are indexing a list. Not the dataframe you stored in that list. Store every csv file you have from that directory first, before doing the checking for the not null rows. Once you stored all your files, then do another loop using the list that hold them and there, you just have to check the not null rows.

Comment: Thanks Joe. I tried without checking for the not null rows and it worked (the loop worked without issues and generated new .csv files). I might be wrong but my guess is that it does not like the fact that within my non-empty cells (across the desired column "20201-2.0"), I have strings called the same (i.e. 20201-2.0). Hence I am asking to extract non-empty cells which are strings and not characters. Do you think I could first check this somehow?

Comment: It does not matter if that column has a value at exact spelling to your column name. In checking for not null it will just tag boolean masks for each cell if it is populated or not. But as far as your requirement goes, you have options there. 1.) On first loop, store all csv in a list. On second loop, loop on that list and remove null rows for each dataframe stored there. or 2.) Once you have the csv in the first loop, parse it right away in that column, to get the rows that is not null before storing it into a list. I think 2.) is faster.

Comment: Hi Joe, sorry I am a beginner in Python and did not manage to get it in place. Do you have any recommendations to suggest in the code?

Comment: I'll try. I can't replicate your scenario but try to write it this way.

Comment: Thank you Joe, that would be great.

Comment: Let me add comment to try and describe what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your loop, after you read the file, automatically filter it, before storing it in a list.

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header = 0)    # You read the file in your directory under the variable filename, but it needs to know that you have a column header. Your '20201-2.0' value is a column name right?
df = df[df['20201-2.0'].notnull()]                        # You now get a new dataframe from the one you load, but now you only got the rows in which the column named '20201-2.0' has been populated.
li.append(df)                                             # Store that dataframe in a list called `li`
```

I also noticed that in the saving as new csv file you have, you are adding `"new"` string and `".csv"` string in each `filname` string variable you have.

Have you ran this code? Does it not save your file as `"something.csvnew.csv"`?

Comment: Thank you Joe. I followed your instructions before and already did it, but I got this error:

Comment: Does your csv file have headers? Is '`20201-2.0'` a column name in your file?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/giorgos/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2657, in get_loc return self._engine.get_loc(key)
File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: '20201-2.0'

Comment: And continues as:

Comment: Exactly what I thought. You are trying to check if the `'20201-2.0'` Column is populated or not, you must declare in reading the csv that you have one. `header = 0`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
df = df[df['20201-2.0'].notnull()]
File "/home/giorgos/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2927, in __getitem__
indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
File "/home/giorgos/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2659, in get_loc
return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

Comment: Can you send a snippet of the csv file? How does it look.

Comment: Yes it is a column name, and the same name continues across the column whenever there is a non-empty cell. You can access a csv file here (you need to run your desktop excel to see this as it is rather big for online reading). https://uoe-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/gpapanas_ed_ac_uk/Eby8Gq1FOXxCuvKeC8d1CHEBbRM7uzl2mss9EhauWSXJ6w?rtime=yi0GmElS10g

Comment: A screenshot will do? Edit your question add the screenshot there. I cannot access your file. Hehe

Comment: No problem. Here it is. https://uoe-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/gpapanas_ed_ac_uk/EayBblFTHmVJvRfsB6h8Vr4B09IfjQ2L1I5OQKUN2p5wzw?e=2gXW61

Comment: These are not exactly the same, I need the 20201-2.0 (the one in between 20200-0.1 and 20202-2.0)!. In other words, this is column LCE. Does it make sense?

Comment: Oh the code in the answer should work then? `read_csv(filename, header = 0)`

Comment: Haha this post has a lot of comments already. Anyway, from what I know `KeyError: '20201-2.0' `means that while parsing the file, it did not see a column named `'20201-2.0'`